# How to add a \addtoreset mechanism to pure TeX \newcount?

Tags: macros, enumerate, subfloats, tex-core, counters

I'm using `subfig` package for sub-figures, thus I'm trying to create a scheme to add a enumeration inside the label to make it easier to describe the sub-pictures. Using `\begin{enumerate*}` and `\begin{inparaenum}` is tedious because I need to instantiate them everytime, I tried to use a `\newcounter` but I don't know why it gives lots of csname error when I put it inside caption and use `refstepcounter{x}`.

Then I came accross pure TeX `\newcount` and it gives no error within caption

I have developed my own minimal functional example

```
\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1
\newcommand{\slb}{(\textit{\@alph\cnt}){ }\advance\cnt by 1 }

\newcommand{\slrt}{\cnt 1 \relax}
\newcommand{\lbl}[1]{\label{#1}\slrt}
```

Where `\slb` shows an increasing numbering alph and `\slrt` resets the numbering, I then wrapped label command inside my own `\lbl` which resets it by the end of a figure.

However it would be more accurate if it could behave like a LaTeX counter with \addtoreset feature to it.

Is it possible to add such a feat? And if yes, how so?

EDIT: minimal working example
What I'm trying to do is to remove the hassle to create a enumeration inside the caption tag

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:sub-0}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \label{fig:sub-1}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
    \label{fig:sub-2}}
\caption[Example]{Example: (\textit{a}) I'm trying, 
                           (\textit{b}) to make 
                           (\textit{c}) this enumerating easier.}
\label{fig:ex-0}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Where I simply replace the `(\textit{a})` with `\slb`

Comment: It should be possible, since LaTeX counters are abstractions on top of `\count`s. However it's probably more work than it's worth. If you just want to put `\refstepcounter{x}` inside a caption, then use `\protect\refstepcounter{x}`. However you'll get weird results, because this `\refstepcounter` will go to the list of figures and your counter will increase there as well. Better use `\caption[List of figures caption]{Document caption and \refstepcounter{x}}`.

Comment: It would be far better if you could provide the full context in the form of a minimal working example. `\caption`s are fragile and there might be a better way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: why not simply use `\newcounter` as adding the missing definitions to make the reset system work is exactly equivalent to using the latex defintion

Comment: you do not want `\newcount` or `\newcounter` _inside_ a `\caption` you do not want to allocate a new register every caption, just allocate it once in the preamble (although sub figures _already_ have a counter so it isn't clear what you aim to do at all to be honest)

Comment: I have provided a minimal working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular `\newcounter` that is reset with every use of `\caption` inside a `figure`. Then `\slb` can just step this counter and set it. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
  justification = centering,
  singlelinecheck = false
}

\newcounter{subfigcntr}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigcntr}{(\textit{\alph{subfigcntr}})}
\newcommand{\slb}{\stepcounter{subfigcntr}\thesubfigcntr~}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption[Example]{Example: \slb I'm trying, 
                             \slb to make 
                             \slb this enumerating easier.}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  ~
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=0.18\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption[Example]{Example: \slb I'm trying, 
                             \slb to make 
                             \slb this enumerating easier.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, this approach works, however `\subfloat[]` requires `\centering` to be centered, any way to make this the default behavior?

Comment: @richard_ba; Yes. Add `justification = centering` to your `\captionsetup`. I've updated the answer and removed the manual use of `\centering`.